# Combine multiple Selenium waits using "OR"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My selenium code checks for a completed subroutine to be done by waiting on the site's title to change which worked perfectly. Code looks like this:

```
waitUntilDone = WebDriverWait(session, 15).until(EC.title_contains(somestring))
```

However, this can fail sometimes since the site's landing page changes after manual website visits. The server remembers where you left off. This forces me to check for an alternate condition (website title = "somestring2).

Here is what I came up with so far (also works as far as I can tell):

```
    try:
        waitUntilDone = WebDriverWait(session, 15).until(EC.title_contains(somestring)) # the old condition
    except:
        try:
            waitUntilDone = WebDriverWait(session, 15).until(EC.title_contains(somestring2)) # the new other condition which is also valid
        except:
            print "oh crap" # we should never reach this point
```

**Either one of these conditions is always true. I don't know which one thou.**

**Is there any way to include an "OR" inside these waits or make the try/except block look nicer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like selenium will let you do this by creating your own class. Check out the documentation here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Here's a quick example for your case. Note the key is to have a method named `__call__` in your class that defines the check you want. Selenium will call that function every 500 milliseconds until it returns True or some not null value.

```
class title_is_either(object):

  def __init__(self, locator, string1, string2):
    self.locator = locator
    self.string1 = string1
    self.string2 = string2

  def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
    title = element.text
    if self.string1 in title or self.string2 in title
        return element
    else:
        return False

# Wait until an element with id='ID-of-title' contains text from one of your two strings
somestring = "Title 1"
somestring2 = "Title 2"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(title_is_either((By.ID, 'ID-of-title'), somestring, somestring2))
```

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow: why do I need to find the title again and what is the title's ID? Can there be more than one page title?

Comment: EC.title_contains (the bit in your code) is just a convenience method that finds the title of the page and compares it to the value you pass it. Under the hood, it has to manually find the <title> element of the web page -- in my snippet, I find the <title> element by searching for its ID (the (By.ID, 'ID-of-title') bit.) 

Hope that helps -- I'd be happy to clarify further.

Comment: To find the ID of the title you would need to right click on the web page, click "inspect element" to view the page source, then search for the title tag (most likely up at the top).

Alternatively to select the title element you could, in my snippet, replace (By.ID, 'ID-of-title') with (By.TAG_NAME, 'title'). There are many ways to select an element as described [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by)

Comment: Were you able to successfully implement this?

Comment: The issue got paused and I need to work on other stuff right now. I will look over your snippet, implement it and flag it as an answer once I get back to it.